# Android : how to combine Fragment of swipeable screen with button activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-fragments, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to make a swipeable screen that has menu buttons, e.g: order, search, etc. (Just imagine it is like your android homescreen). If the button is clicked, it will lead to other page and start activity.

The problem is, I can make the screen swipeable but I can't connect the button in my fragment to another java when it is clicked.
How to make this possible?

Here is my code:

```
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     View tab2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_dua, container, false);

     B_vStock = (Button) tab2.findViewById(R.id.BtnStock);
     B_vStock.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent z= new Intent(Tab_Dua.this, View_Stock.class);  ==> error on this
            startActivity(z);
        }
    });
```

**swipeable layout (XML)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TableRow 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:gravity="center">

            <ImageButton 
                android:src="@drawable/ord"
                android:id="@+id/img_up_order"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

            <ImageButton 
                android:src="@drawable/stock"
                android:id="@+id/BtnStock"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "I can't use findViewById" -> Why not ? In your Fragment, you use view.findViewById inside onCreateView...

Comment: thanks for reply, I updated question a bit.. Just realized, I just did a silly mistake for last question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent z= new Intent(Tab_Dua.this, View_Stock.class);
```

Assuming Tab_Dua is a `Fragment`, you cannot do this, [the constructor of Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)) will not accept a `Fragment`, it takes a `Context`. You could do this :

```
Intent z= new Intent(Tab_Dua.this.getActivity(), View_Stock.class);
```